# CakePHP redirect in a class

Tags: php, class, cakephp, plugins

I have write a plugin class and I want to make a redirect inside it but doesn't work.
How can I solve?
This is my call inside a controller to the plugin:

```
      public function action(){
                $permissions = new Permissions();
                $rules = array('some_value');
                $permissions->allow($rules);
      }
```

And this is my class:

```
class Permissions {
    public function __construct(array $settings = array()) {

    }

    public function allow($rules) {
        //some check
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

This code return me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Permissions::redirect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the exact code of your class then the reason you can't use `$this->redirect('/');` is because your class isn't extending any other class and so isn't inheriting the functions .

It should look like this:

```
class PermissionsController extends PermissionsPluginAppController {
    public function __construct(array $settings = array()) {

    }

    public function allow($rules) {
        //some check
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

See the docs here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-controllers

Comment: no is a class inside a plugin without controller at the moment, only inside folder Plugin/Permissions/Vendor

Comment: Well that is why you are getting that error then. The redirect function is in CakePHP's Controller class so as you aren't extending that class the function doesn't exist.

Comment: well, how can I create a controller inside the plugin directory , load it inside for example UserController, and call the action allow where I have my redirect? Can you create an example please?

Comment: It seems that you perhaps misunderstand what plugins are and how they should be used. The general idea is that a plugin can be loaded onto any application and used as if they are part of the application. So you wouldnt call a plugin controller from within an application's controller but the controller in the plugin should essentially become part of the application. If your class is currently in the vendor part of the plugin can you not just put it in the applications vendor folder? Also Im not sure a file in the vendor folder should really be redirecting anyway pehaps it should return a result

Comment: I haven't to return a value for example I have only to manage permission to see pages. Can you please explain with an example how to convert my class into a controller of a plugin and how to call it please? because I have read documentation of cake but I haven't really understand how to do it, please.. thanks

Comment: Unless you are planning on distributing this so other people can use it there is really no need for it to be a plugin. Controllers in plugins work exactly like controllers in the app folder. I can't explain better than the docs I'm afraid so perhaps you should look to implement it in your app and once you have done that then move it into a plugin (if you actually need/want to do that).

Comment: Ok I have seen and understand, the nly thing that I don't nderstnd and is how to load this controller from example UsersController, and call the action allow, can you help me please?

Comment: Like I said you don't load a controller from another controller. You just need to create the appropriate views for the permissions controller.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this, I did not try this but may work

```
public function allow($rules) {
    //some check
    Router::redirect(
        '/home/*',
        array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
    );
}
```